# Tight curves in a plot in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have four curves to plot in Python, each one corresponds to a certain value of a parameter γ. As one may see in the figure, the four curves are really tight with almost no distinction between them. I would like to do a plot as the one in the figure and to add a subplot inside where the difference of the lines could be seen.

[image]

I tried reducing the scales but it looks impossible.
Is there a in-built way in matplotlib to see these differences?
[Here is a csv file with the values of each curve!](https://github.com/elopezfune/Z_curves/blob/master/z_curves.csv)

Comment: If you mean to illuminate the differences between each curve, what if you actually plot `curve1 - curve0`, `curve2 - curve0`, etc.?

Comment: [This example code](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/zoom_inset_axes.html) from the tutorials shows how to create a zoomed-in plot.

Comment: thanks @JohanC
I had to walk around a bit the example you posted, but I managed to do it

Comment: What about using a log scale (or exponential) on the y-axis?

Comment: @Dan I tried all that without success before posting the question. Check up the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Well, thanks to @JohanC I found a walk around solution on https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/zoom_inset_axes.html

```
dataframe = pd.read_csv('z_curves.csv')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
r=dataframe['rad']
z_2=dataframe['z_2']
z_4=dataframe['z_4']
z_6=dataframe['z_6']
z_8=dataframe['z_8']

ax.plot(r,z_2,"k")
ax.plot(r,z_4,"k--")
ax.plot(r,z_6,"k:")
ax.plot(r,z_8,"k-.")
ax.plot(r,[0.0 for i in range(len(r))],"g--")
ax.set_xlabel('$r/r_c$',fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel('$e^{\\nu(r)}-1$',fontsize=20)
plt.xlim(0.0,1.0)
plt.ylim(-0.000001,0.0000001)
targets = ["$\gamma=0.2$", "$\gamma=0.4$", "$\gamma=0.6$", "$\gamma=0.8$"]
legend = plt.legend(targets,loc='best', shadow=True)
legend.get_frame().set_facecolor('white')
axins = ax.inset_axes([0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4])
x1, x2, y1, y2 = 0.2, 0.201, -5.5634547184309856e-08, -5.5606744002038696e-08
axins.set_xlim(x1, x2-0.0008)
axins.plot(r,z_2,"k")
axins.plot(r,z_4,"k--")
axins.plot(r,z_6,"k:")
axins.plot(r,z_8,"k-.")
axins.set_ylim(y1, y2)
axins.set_xticklabels('')
axins.set_yticklabels('')
ax.indicate_inset_zoom(axins)
plt.show()
```

[image]